# Odoo invoice items that need to be associated to different analytic accounts

Tags: odoo

We need to invoice donations that are linked to an analytics account.
We have about 400 projects for which a user can make a donation. 
A project is linked to a analytic account and only 1 donation per invoice.

As I understand it correctly, OpenERP/Odoo uses an invoice based on the analytic account to which it is associated at item level.

This would mean that we need to add for every new project/analytic account a new product item to invoice that is linked to the analytic account.

I find this not a good maintainable approach.

So what would be a other approach to invoice projects and make sure that the invoice item is linked to the analytic account?

Comment: Which analytics account? Google Analytics? Something else?

Answer (score 0):

you are right in odoo you need to select analytic account manually for each associated item.

what you need to do is if you want to set auto analytic account when product will be selected on invoice line.

Create custom module add m2o field inside product and override the on change method of invoice line which will automatically set the analytic account.